# Selenium-Extent_Reports: Not able to view the failure screenshots on other Computer/Machine

Tags: selenium-webdriver, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

-Failure Screenshot are visible in Extent_Reports on my local machine. But not able to view the failure screenshot in Extent_Reports on other Computer/Machine.

-When i trigger build from Jenkins, After build successful, Sending email to:Recipient List

**To Capture Screenshot**

```
    public String captureScreen(String fileName) {
    if(fileName =="") {
        fileName="Screenshot";  }

    File destFile=null;
    Calendar calendar =Calendar.getInstance() ;
    SimpleDateFormat formater= new SimpleDateFormat("dd_MM_yyy_hh_mm_ss");
    File srcFile=((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

    try {

         String reportDirectory = "/src/main/java/com/test/automation/Demo/screenshot/";
         //String reportDirectory= new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")).getAbsolutePath()+"./src/main/java/com/test/automation/Demo/screenshot/";
         destFile= new File((String)reportDirectory + fileName +"-" + formater.format(calendar.getTime())+ ".png");
         FileUtils.copyFile(srcFile,destFile );
         //This will help us to link screen shot in Extent report
         Reporter.log("<a href='"+destFile+ "'><img src='" +destFile+"' height='100' width='100'/></a>");
         //Reporter.log("<a href='"+destFile.getAbsolutePath()+ "'><img src='" +destFile.getAbsolutePath()+"' height='100' width='100'/></a>");
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return destFile.toString();
}
```

**For generating Extent reports with screenshots for Failure test cases**

```
 public void getresult(ITestResult result) {

if(result.getStatus()==ITestResult.FAILURE) 
{
  test.log(LogStatus.ERROR, result.getName()+" Test case FAILED due to below issues: "+result.getThrowable());
  String screen = captureScreen("");
  test.log(LogStatus.FAIL," Failure Screenshot : "+ test.addScreenCapture(screen));
    }}
```

Comment: could you explain bit more whats the issue

Comment: Unable to view failure screenshot in Extent Reports html file on other machine but in local machine failure screenshots are visible.

Answer (score 2):

If You're using remoteWebDriver than it must be augmented before you can use the screenshot capability. Did You try to

```
WebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver();
driver = new Augmenter().augment(driver);

// or for mobile driver

androidDriver.setFileDetector(new LocalFileDetector()); 
//this is needed when using remoteDriver
```

Here is how I take screenshot for ExtentReport

```
File scrFile = driver.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

String dest = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/resources/screenshots/" + dataMethod.getAndroidDriver().getSessionId() + ".png";

File destination = new File(dest);
try {
    FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, destination);

    // this is just utility which takes screenshot and copy it to desired destination 

     dataMethod.setScreenshotPath(destination.getAbsolutePath());
} catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And on code failure:

```
@Override
public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    setTestEndTime(result);

    ExtentTest extentTest = methodData.getExtentTest();           
    extentTest.addScreenCaptureFromPath(methodData.getScreenshotPath());
}
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: i'm not using remoteWebDriver

Answer (score 2):

I didn't used Extent reports, i have my own implementation for reports. But i am expecting is there is issue with src

```
<img src='" +destFile+"' height='100' width='100'/></a>");
```

Here, destFile brings location of image or screenshot which is related to your machine. the same should not be works for others. We have to use relative path, see this

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

And also make sure that when sharing reports, it should contains all requires files and folders also.

Comment: How to sharing screenshots, Extent-Report folder?

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the issue happens as the local files are not allowed to be loaded. So even we put relative or absolute path, that seems not work for many cases. 
So I try to take base64screenshot instead, and it displays quite good in Extent Report. 
To have the screenshot in folder report, just need to take screenshot as usual.

```
public static String getBase64Screenshot(WebDriver driver, String screenshotName) throws IOException {
    String encodedBase64 = null;
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = null;
    TakesScreenshot screenshot = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
    File source = screenshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    String destination = windowsPath + "\\FailedTestsScreenshots\\"+screenshotName+timeStamp+".png";
    File finalDestination = new File(destination);
    FileUtils.copyFile(source, finalDestination);

    try {
        fileInputStream =new FileInputStream(finalDestination);
        byte[] bytes =new byte[(int)finalDestination.length()];
        fileInputStream.read(bytes);
        encodedBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return encodedBase64;
}
```

Call it in failure cases:

```
public synchronized void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
    System.out.println("==="+methodDes + "=== failed!");
    try {
        WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) result.getTestContext().getAttribute("driver");
        String base64Screenshot = ExtentManager.getBase64Screenshot(driver, result.getName());
        MediaEntityModelProvider mediaModel = MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String(base64Screenshot).build();
        test.get().fail("image:", mediaModel);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    test.get().fail(result.getThrowable().getMessage());
}
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem...If I check the extent report html source, then images are not loaded with error: "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///C:/Program%20Files/Jenkins/workspace/XXX_Automation/Reports/addTest.png". I have tried your suggestion to take base64screenshot instead but in vain. . It's not the content security policy thing. Please note that I have checked the path- It's correct. Suggest me!